# How to build indoor navigation for a railway station?

Tags: android, ibeacon, beacon, eddystone, indoor-positioning-system

I want to build an android app for indoor navigation of a railway station. Is it possible through beacons? I was wondering if I can use beacons as a starting point reference and then use the accelerometer and other sensors to calculate speed and direction.

If I want to implement it through beacons, which beacons should I go for? Beacons with great development support would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Esimote is the most used beacon.

You can write a program for it using Android beacon library as well.

Here in Stackoverflow questions need to be more direct and more code related.